# How to print the result of JSON to the output file?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, permalinks

The output of the JSON file has multiple responses like the one seen below

```
"response_code":1

"scan_date":"2011-07-27 03:44:56"

"permalink":"https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1caea01fd9a6c6d12e5ca46007e25a4b1eff640060f45de8213e40aa5b47cd57/detection/f-1caea01fd9a6c6d12e5ca46007e25a4b1eff640060f45de8213e40aa5b47cd57-1311738296"

"verbose_msg":"Scan finished, information embedded"

"total":43

"positives":19
```

The below code will get the value of "positives" in the JSON output and then print it to the file.

```py
    # DOES THE HASH EXISTS IN VT DATABASE?
    if response == 0:
        print(hash + ": UNKNOWN")
        file = open(output,"a")
        file.write(hash + " 0")
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()

    # DOES THE HASH EXISTS IN VT DATABASE?
    elif response == 1:
        positives = int(json_response.get("positives"))
        if positives >= 3:
            print(hash + ": MALICIOUS")
            file = open(output,"a")
            file.write(hash + " " + str(positives))
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
        else:
            print(hash + ": NOT MALICIOUS")
            file = open(output,"a")
            file.write(hash + " 0")
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
    else: print(hash + ": CAN NOT BE SEARCHED")
```

So the result of the current code will be something like the below

```
0136b7453cedf600d6f6aab7900901d3            19
```

I am trying to get the value of "permalink" in the JSON results and print it in the same output file. So the output must look like the below

```
0136b7453cedf600d6f6aab7900901d3 19 https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1caea01fd9a6c6d12e5ca46007e25a4b1eff640060f45de8213e40aa5b47cd57/detection/f-1caea01fd9a6c6d12e5ca46007e25a4b1eff640060f45de8213e40aa5b47cd57-1311738296
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read it the same way you read the positive values.

```
elif response == 1:
    positives = int(json_response.get("positives"))
    permalink = json_response.get("permalink")
    if positives >= 3:`enter code here`
        print(hash + ": MALICIOUS" + " | URL:" + permalink)
        file = open(output,"a")`enter code here`
        file.write(hash + " " + str(positives))
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
```